# How to make a JAR from two projects?

Tags: eclipse, jar

I have one project PROJECT1 (containing Main Class for MANIFEST), which is using classes defined within another project, PROJECT2. When I create JAR by exporting PROJECT1 into JAR and then run it, it seems like the classes defined within PROJECT2 are not included. How can I fix this? I am working in Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Are you working on JavaProject or PluginProject?

Comment: What is the difference and how can I find it out which project am I working on?

Comment: see it in your project's `.project` file and check the `<nature>` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In the dialog that opens after you right click on 'Export..' and then 'Jar File', you can choose which dependencies are to be included. Continue with 'Next' and at some point you will be asked to specify a Manifest and then there's a 'Select the Main Class'.